# How to reset $GOROOT

Tags: go, terminal

I have wrongly set goroot path in terminal and can't excecute anything. I have now been told I should not touch $GOROOT. What is correct default value for $GOROOT or can I set it to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to set GOROOT at all (*). Find where it's set in your profile (like `.bashrc` or comparable file for your shell/system/OS) and remove that. Go will do just fine without GOROOT set and confusion will be avoided.

---

(*) Unless you're doing strange things like downloading a binary distribution of Go and installing it on a location that's not standard.